# set a default div (CSS transitions)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

My goal is to create a page with 3 absolutely positioned, overlapping divs.  Only 1 div should be visible at a time.  3 buttons at the bottom of the page are used to "select" each div with a fade-in/out using CSS transitions.

I'm close but I have a small issue.

Currently, upon initialization the page is blank with 3 buttons.  
**My question is**, how do I have the first div (with id="#1") appear by default upon initialization without the need to press a button.  I still want div #1 to follow the normal fade-in/fade-out rules, with the exception of upon initialization.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="1" class="inner">One</div>
<div id="2" class="inner">Two</div>
<div id="3" class="inner">Three</div>

<a href="#1" class="button">Toggle One</a>
<a href="#2" class="button">Toggle Two</a>
<a href="#2" class="button">Toggle Three</a>
```

**SOME CSS**:

```
.inner{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear .5s, opacity .5s linear;
}
.inner:target{
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

I would prefer a solution that doesn't use javascript/jQuery but I'm not against it if necessary.

Comment: ID's are invalid, they cannot start with a number

Comment: sorry I was merely using placeholders.  Didn't know that integer IDs are invalid though, good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you will need to use JavaScript/jQuery at a minimum to set the visibility of the `#1` div on load.  You can do this with CSS via:

```
.inner:first-of-type {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74qYY/

The restriction there is that a background is required to obscure the other divs.  If you can't live with that, you can always use JS: http://jsfiddle.net/74qYY/1/

Comment: ah I see.  Interesting, I didn't think of using a background on ".inner" to obscure the default.  Definitely works for my question case!  Unfortunately probably won't extrapolate to the real-world-problem I was trying to solve, but that's what javascript is for I guess.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I found a round-about way to preserve the CSS transitions without  requiring a background.  Specifically I used the url fragments set by the buttons.

In the question, I wanted div "#1" to show as default.  Another way to look at this is that I wanted a GET request of "/" to redirect to "/#1".

I used some jQuery to check for the absence of a URL fragment and then redirect to www.url.com/#1, which in turn triggers the CSS transition.